# Action bar text color is showing different in different devices

Tags: android, android-actionbar

In my app I set my actionbar text color to white . But if I test my on on a different device (API-21) the color change to black . I want to show it white in every devices .

[Screenshot](http://i59.tinypic.com/28cge40.png)

As you can see in the attached image , text color of "Cart" is black . But it is supposed to white . How can I make it white to all devices

Comment: Wha API lvl shows correct behaviour, which is showing the wrong one? I assume you haven't set the text to white for all api-lvls :)

Comment: In api 17 it shows white which I exactly want

Comment: post your styles.xmls with correspondign versions.